# Expose VSTO Ribbon to VisibleChanged event in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am creating an application level add-in for Word 2010 using C# VSTO. I want to access the `get_Pressed` callback method for the add-in's ribbon when the add-in's Custom Task Pane is hidden or made visible. However, in order to do so, I need the ribbon to be made available to the `myTaskPane_VisibleChanged` event in the `ThisAddIn` class. I cannot use the `Ribbons` collection because the ribbon in the add-in was created in Ribbon XML and not with Visual Studio's Ribbon Designer.

In the `ThisAddIn` class I have:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    myTaskPane.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(myTaskPane_VisibleChanged);
}
```

and

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    return new myRibbon();
    //I tried playing with IRibbonExtension here, but could not get that to work
}
```

and

```
public void myTaskPane_VisibleChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Here is where I would like to access the ribbon
    //I think the command would look something like:
    //myRibbon.IsTaskPaneVisible = !myRibbon.IsTaskPaneVisible;
   //myRibbon is not accessible here
}
```

In the myRibbon class I have:

```
public class myRibbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
    public Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

    private bool isTaskPaneVisible;

    public bool IsTaskPaneVisible
    {
        get { return isTaskPaneVisible; }
        set
        {
            isTaskPaneVisible = value;
            ribbon.InvalidateControl("rxtglElementsPane");
        }
    }
```

and

```
public bool rxtglElementsPane_get_Pressed(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    try
    {
        switch (control.Id)
        {
            case "rxtglElementsPane":
                return isTaskPaneVisible;
            default:
                return false;
        }       
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Most of this code is based on this article:

[Synchronizing Ribbon and Task Pane](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2006/10/20/synchronizing-ribbon-and-task-pane.aspx)

where in the comments the author mentions that generated code in the `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject` includes the instantiation of the ribbon. When I created the add-in there was no such code generated by Visual Studio 2013.

Any help in accessing the ribbon from the `ThisAddIn` class would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starain Chen of the MSDN Visual Studio forum provided me with the answer from a post I placed there:

[MSDN Expose VSTO Ribbon to VisibleChanged event in C# Answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bae3a35d-7da6-41e1-a793-8e305c973ce4/expose-vsto-ribbon-to-visiblechanged-event-in-c?forum=vsto)

The solution was to define a field/property to the `ThisAddIn` class with the `myRibbon` type.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
   internal myRibbon myRibbon;
   ...
    protected override Office.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        myRibbon=new myRibbon();
        return myRibbon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to access the ribbon objects. Instead, you may access the add-in class using the Globals.ThisAddin property. See [Global Access to Objects in Office Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhczd18c.aspx) for more information. Thus, you will be able to modify any local variables that can be used in the Ribbon callbacks.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @EugeneAstafiev. I cannot access any `myRibbon` callbacks, properties or methods from `myTaskPane_VisibleChanged` using the `Globals.ThisAddin` class or other classes. IntelliSense has no access to `myRibbon`. "There is no applicable variable or member" messages display. I do not see how the links apply to accessing the `_get_Pressed` callback or `myRibbon` properties when the `myTaskPane_VisibleChanged` event is triggered. Would you be able to give me one or two lines of code that access the callback? Or provide some reason why the `ThisAddin` and `myRibbon` classes cannot communicate?